# get left table rows from right table conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join, group-concat

I have three tables like this:

person:

```
  id   |  name  |  gender
---------------------------
  1       Joe       male
  2       Daniel    male
  3       Sarah     female
```

person_skills:

```
  person_id  |  skill_id
---------------------------
      1            1
      1            2
      1            3
      2            1
      2            2
...
```

skills:

```
  id  |  skill_name
-----------------------
  1       Writing
  2       Programming
  3       Singing
...
```

I need to get all the skills of persons when I just send one of their skills in my query.

This is my code:

```
SELECT a.name, a.gender, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.skill_name), 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.id as skill_id) 
FROM persons a 
LEFT JOIN person_skills b ON b.person_id = a.id 
LEFT JOIN skills c ON c.id = b.skill_id
WHERE b.skill_id = 3 GROUP BY a.id
```

I want the result:

```
 name  |  gender  |  skill_name  |  skill_id
----------------------------------------------
 Joe      male       Writing           1
                     Programming       2
                     Singing           3
```

But this code return only skill_id "3" and skill_name "Singing".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your SQL doesn't even make sense as it's referencing columns that don't exist... but just the same, are you meaning to ask: "How do I get a list of all skills for any person that has the skill "Singing""?

Comment: Ignoring the typos, you'll need to reference `person_skills` twice; first to get persons with skill 3, and again to get the skills of those people.

Comment: Change your WHERE clause to `WHERE a.id = (SELECT b.person_id FROM person_skills WHERE skill_id = 3)` and I think you'll have what you are after.

Comment: @Uueerdo Yes, I tried it and worked fine. But I'm looking for a faster way.

Comment: @Jake there is not likely a faster way unless you were doing it differently than I assume (see my answer for example). More table references doesn't necessarily equal slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to reference some tables twice.

```
SELECT p.name, p.gender, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.skill_name), 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.id as skill_id) 
FROM person_skills AS ps0
INNER JOIN persons AS p ON ps0.person_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN person_skills ps ON p.id = ps.person_id 
LEFT JOIN skills s ON s.id = ps.skill_id
WHERE ps0.skill_id = 3 
GROUP BY p.id
```

*Sidenote: I left it alone, but your grouping criteria can be problematic under certain configurations.*

...and alternative, if you averse to the extra table references, but unlikely to be faster is:

```
SELECT p.name, p.gender, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.skill_name), 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.id as skill_id) 
FROM persons AS p 
LEFT JOIN person_skills ps ON p.id = ps.person_id 
LEFT JOIN skills s ON s.id = ps.skill_id
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING COUNT(CASE s.skill_id WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL) > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I should use your first method.

Comment: Yeah, the second method basically collects the information for everyone, and then eliminates the unwanted data after doing all the work. It can be technically faster for very small data sets, but in those situations the speed differences seen are usually trivial.